# Discrete Mathematics Group Theory

Tags: group-theory

Let G be a group of the identity element 1 and a, b, c ∈ G
a. Given that x ∈ G fulfills

```
                         {ax^(2) = b
                         {x^(3) = 1 what is x.
```

b.Given that x ∈ G fulfills

```
                        {(xax)^(3) = b*x
                        { x2a = (xa)^(−1) what is x.
```

I have a formua Identity There is an element e in G such that e*x = x*e = x but after that i get stuck anyone with hints to proceed!

Comment: $a,b,c$ are any 3 elements of $G$ or $G$ has only $a,b,c$ as elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x^3=1$ and $ax^2=b$. Then right multiplying second equality with $x$, $ax^3=bx$ implying $a=bx$ implying $x=b^{-1}a$.

Next we have $(xax)^3=bx$ and $x^2a=(xa)^{-1}$. Expanding the first quantity we see $xax^2ax^2ax=bx$ and post-multiplying by $x^{-1}$ we get $xax^2ax^2a=b$ The second equality gives $x^2axa=1=xax^2a$. So write $b=xax^2ax^2a=x^2a$. Substituting in $1=xax^2a$ we get $1=xab$ implying $x=(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$.